# Get tweets a specific account retweeted?

Tags: twitter

I was looking at the twitter API, and I couldn't tell if the api allows you to pull your tweets that others have retweeted, or tweets you retweeted.  What I'm trying to do is pull in the most recent tweet an account retweeted.  I figured if the retweet api didn't do this I could just pull in the timeline and loop through until I reach the last retweet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These calls will help:

> Returns 20 of the most recent retweets posted by the authenticating
>   user http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweeted_by_me.json
>
> Returns 20 of the most recent tweets of the authenticated user that
>   have been retweeted by others
>   http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweets_of_me.json
>
> Returns 20 of the most recent retweets posted by the authenticating
>   users friends http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweeted_to_me.json

Each works for your own account.

Comment: Now if I want to embed this into a website and pull in the websites twitter account, could you point me to the step to authenticate first?